# Fourier series discontinuous function

Tags: fourier-series

I'm trying to find the Fourier series for:
$$ r_a(x)=\left\{\begin{array} & \frac{1}{2a} \quad |x|<a \\
0 \quad a<|x|<\pi \end{array}\right.$$

I'm having problems because of the discontinuity and I'm ask to find the values for the Fourier series for the discontinuity point and the end of the interval.

Comment: You have a formula for the Fourier coefficients. Why not use it?

Comment: Part, of my problem, is that from what, I know the formula, that my teacher gave me was only for continuos function, thats why I'm asking.

Comment: Mmmm really? I bet you were given a formula for any Riemann integrable function.

Comment: I'll check again then, maybe the teacher for got to tell, or gave it as a given, that  it was for Riemann integrable function.